# Equivalent of 'ssh' config option in Hg for Git?

Tags: windows, git, hg

On Windows 7, my `.hgrc` config file provides a nice an easy way to tell Mercurial about the private SSH key location with the following syntax:

```
[ui]
username = John Doe <jdoe@example.com>
ssh = plink.exe -i "C:\Users\jdoe\mykeys.ppk"
```

Does anyone knows what is the equivalent syntax for the `.gitconfig` file? All I can find so far is the `GIT_SSH` environment variable that does not seem to let me specify the private key location.

Comment: Is the key used for all SSH connections, or must it limited to hg/git?

Comment: All connections is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify a key to be used for all connections, there are two ways to do it with PuTTY:

1. Load the key into Pageant, the SSH agent program. Just double-click the .ppk file and enter its passphrase, if any.

   This has several advantages: you can encrypt the key on disk and still retain the convenience of password-less logins, and you can have multiple keys loaded and they all will be tried.

   (The OpenSSH equivalent of Pageant is *ssh-agent*, by the way.)
2. Edit PuTTY's default configuration to point to the key. Open a new PuTTY window, go to *Connection → SSH → Auth*, and choose your key file under *Private key file*. Go back to *Session*, click the "Default Settings" item, and click *Save*.

   `plink` uses the same session settings as PuTTY, and will automatically use the key you configured here.

   (In OpenSSH, you would edit `~/.ssh/config` to achieve the same result.)